# MongoDB connects only for the first time and fails to connect if app service is restarted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am having Node.JS application with database as Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB. The application is hosted in azure app service. Everything works just fine after the application is deployment, but if the app service is restarted, the DB reconnection fails with timeout error message.

Here is the connection script

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb'); 

module.exports = {
    client: client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI),
    connectToDB: async () => {
        try {
            await client.connect();
            console.log('connected!')
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Err', err)
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting the below connection timeout error

```
Err MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:292:38)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    servers: Map {
      'xxx.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'globaldb',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set {}
}
```

Comment: Did you whitelist your IP?

Comment: Yes, It is already whitelisted and connection is established, working fine after deployment but incase if I restart the app service manually, this error pops up. I again need to redeploy the app service to make it work

Comment: Maybe try standard port 27017 instead of 10255

Comment: Our CosmoDB for MongoDB runs only in the port 10255

Comment: Maybe it is blocked by network firewall, see https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=10255